# Better breakdown of Python profiling

Tags: python, profiling

Is there some sort of tool that can give me a more visual representation of the output from Python's `profile`/`cProfile` tools (or any other profiling module)?  It works well with simple scripts, but I'm using a couple libraries so I get several pages of little library calls that are basically noise (<1 ms time used) when trying to figure out what's the actual time sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) is a popular choice.

Here's a PyCon Canada talk about profiling, which mentions RunSnakeRun among others: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUf-ALvk3cU

Comment: Looks just like what I pictured it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in timing only particular fragments of your code and want to avoid seeing noise from other places, you can try [Region Profiler](https://github.com/metopa/region_profiler). Only code regions you've marked are measured. Apart from the summary, you can then see a flame graph in Chrome Trace Viewer.